# Displaying several float numbers as one

Tags: python, python-3.x

For the life of me, I can't seem to get the numbers to add up! They are all printing separately. For example, it is displaying "That will be $95.00 $90 $8.50 for the ..." I think it's as simple as getting the bracket numbers correct.. but I can't seem to do it!

```
print("That is " + str((formatC(pack[packageSelect-1]["adult"]*noAdult) + formatC(pack[packageSelect-1]["child"]*noChild) + (formatC(AREAS.get(delivery))))) + "for " + pack[packageSelect]["name"] +  " package for " + str(noAdult) + " " + adult + " and ", str(noChild) + " " + child + ",  delivered to " + str(deliveryArea.title()) + ".")
```

I want the "adult" + "child" + "delivery" to be a total.. not separate prices!

Comment: Then why not add the numbers *before* turning them to strings?

Comment: What is `formatC` here? Presumably that formats a floating point value?

Comment: What's wrong with grasping the basics of programming (in general, not python specific) before asking questions about why strings do not add up like numbers? How more basic could it get?

Comment: Sometimes it takes a little reminder to remember them. I'm very new to programming in general.. still trying to get my head around it. Probably could get a lot more basic.. like someone asking how to "print" something.

Comment: Yes, formatC formats a floating point number. I have solved my query. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are *adding up* the string representation of those numbers. The `+` operator for strings does concatenation. If you want to add the amounts you will have to do the addition while they are still `float` and then convert the result to string.

Comment: @Meg: sorry, you can only mark *one* answer as accepted per question. Glad we were both of help though!

Answer (score 1):

Your are adding formatted strings; adding strings places them one after the other.

Add the *numbers* first:

```
total = (
    pack[packageSelect-1]["adult"] * noAdult + 
    pack[packageSelect-1]["child"] * noChild + 
    AREAS.get(delivery))
print("That is " + str(formatC(total)) + "for " + pack[packageSelect]["name"] +  " package for " + str(noAdult) + " " + adult + " and ", str(noChild) + " " + child + ",  delivered to " + str(deliveryArea.title()) + ".")
```

You may want to study how you can format strings with [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format); it would make your printing code a whole lot simpler and more readable:

```
print("That is {total} for {pack['name']} package for {noAdult} {adult} and {noChild} {child}, delivered to {area}.".format(
    total=formatC(total), pack=pack[packageSelect], noAdult=noAdult, adult=adult,
    noChild=noChild, child=child, area=deliveryArea.title()))
```